# Как через setText присвоить textView число?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Необходимо конвертировать его в строку?

```
result.setText(valueX); // не катит;
result.setText(valueX + ""); // не нравится
```

Comment: Причем здесь IntelliJ IDEA? можете написать `setText(Integer.toString(valueX))`, так покатит .. вмето Integer указать  примитивный тип объявленный для вашего числа.

Answer (score 6):

Если функции setText() передать целое число, она воспримет его как идентификатор ресурса и будет искать такую строку в ресурсах. Чтобы вывести на View число, нужно сначала его привести к строке. Сделать это можно так:

```
result.setText(Integer.toString(valueX));
```

или так:

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(valueX));
```

или так:

```
result.setText(valueX + "");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!